# Custom price format based on decimal and zeros in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am struggling to find a solution to my price format issue.

If the price in cart adds up to $1 then it should show $1.00 Now, this works if I change the decimal in WC settings to "2".

However, if wanted it to show as 0.065 and 0.010 So I added a "3" in the WC decimal settings. So, how can I get the price to look like this:

- $0.065
- $0.01 (and NOT this 0.010)

I just want to remove the trailing zero if it is a zero.

So I have tried a few things:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'wc_hide_trailing_zeros', 10, 1 );
function wc_hide_trailing_zeros( $trim ) {

    return true;

}
```

This removes ALL zeros.

Then I tried a function that supposed to remove the last item in a str.

```
function rstrtrim($str, $remove=null) 
{ 
    $str    = (string)$str; 
    $remove = (string)$remove;    

    if(empty($remove)) 
    { 
        return rtrim($str); 
    } 

    $len = strlen($remove); 
    $offset = strlen($str)-$len; 
    while($offset > 0 && $offset == strpos($str, $remove, $offset)) 
    { 
        $str = substr($str, 0, $offset); 
        $offset = strlen($str)-$len; 
    } 

    return rtrim($str);    

} 

//Remove last zero on a 3 decimal setting
echo rstrtrim((string)$number_format, '0');
```

But I think it's not working because it is reading it as a string and not an integer, dunno.

So, all I want to do is set my decimal settings in WC to "3" and remove the "last" integer IF it is a zero...

so this:

- $1.000
- $0.065
- $0.010

Would be this:

- $1.00
- $0.065
- $0.01

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out!

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'wc_custom_price_format', 10, 5 );

function wc_custom_price_format( $number_format, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator){

$lastnum = $number_format[strlen($number_format)-1];

if ($lastnum == 0):

   return substr($number_format, 0, -1);

else:

   return $number_format;   

endif;

}
```